# Beginner integral question (about notation)

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been trying to learn calculus and have been using entry level books and what not.

So far I established when getting derivatives it take the derivative of f(x) and end up with the 1st derivate f'(x) and then 2nd f''(x) and so forth.

This is where I then get confused…it seems with integration this use of f(x) changes ? Now f(x) ..(note no use of f'), is actually my differentiated equational I am actually trying to get it back to F(x)

So to summarize, in derivatives we go from f(x) to f'(x), but in differentiation f(x) is actually the equivalent of f'(x) from derivatives ?

Part 2…

U substitution for integration

One lot of info I have has 'special' cases of u substitution for integration. the formula given is g(x) g' (u) dx  = u du

It goes on to say one special case is where f(u) = u . I don't understand . I read this as the derivative of u = u ?

As an example we are asked to integrate sin x cos x dx. We let u = sin x and note that the derivative of sin x is cos x…but this is not the same as f(u) = u

the next special example is f(u) is 1/u. I dont understand how taking the derivative of u can result in 1/u

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at in the second part, but $f(x)$ represents a general function. Thus we can try to take its derivative $f'(x)$ or its antiderivative $\int f(x)\; dx$, often written $F(x)$.

Comment: Why do we need to find the antiderivative of our general function ? This is the first part I am struggling with. i.e why are we trying to find F(x) when our original function was (fx) ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the chain of differentiation:

$$F(x)\rightarrow f(x)\rightarrow f'(x) \rightarrow f''(x)\rightarrow f'''(x)...$$

where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. Integration is kind of the opposite operation of differentiation. So the integration chain goes backward:

$$f'''(x)\rightarrow f''(x)\rightarrow f'(x)\rightarrow f(x)\rightarrow F(x)...$$

You can of course include more or less on both sides.

The substitution rule works this way,

$$\int f(u) u dx = \int f(u) du$$

And then it says in the "special" case $f(u)$ could be just $u$. Notice it says SPECIAL. So in that example, you can write

$$\int \sin{x}\cos{x}dx=\int u du=\frac{1}{2}u^2+C=\frac{1}{2}(\sin{x})^2+C$$

if you let $u=\sin{x}$. In this special case $f(u)=u$. So it does not mean $f(u)$ is the derivative of $u$.

I am not sure what your next example is. But for example, you could have

$$\int \frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx$$

Let $u=x^2+1$, then $du=2xdx$ (which is the differential of $u$). The integral then becomes

$$\int \frac{1}{u} du =\ln{|u|}+C$$

In this case, $f(u)=\frac{1}{u}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @KittyL. The chain of differentiation is the first thing I dont quite understand. In a textbook I may be asked to differentiate a function called f(x), and lets pretend x = x^2. So I get f' (x) = 2x . So taking the antiderivative of f'(x) woudl take me back to f(x). ie. my original function. I dont understand why we go a step further and go back to F(x) when F(x) wasnt our original function .

Comment: In this case, the chain is: $\frac{1}{3}x^3 \rightarrow x^2 \rightarrow 2x \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0....$ and the integration chain is $ 0 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 2x \rightarrow x^2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{3}x^3..$ of course in the latter one there could be a constant difference. It just depends on where you start to look at them. For example, you can say the original function of $2x$ is $x^2$, whereas you can also say the original function of $x^2$ is $\frac{1}{3}x^3$. Or you can say the original function of $2$ is $2x$.

Comment: how does F(x) work in real life ? When might one want to know or use F(x) ? I was under the impression f(x) was the improtant one to pay attention to as it represented our original function.

Comment: If you understand the chain argument, you would see that $F(x)$ IS the original of $f(x)$, and $f(x)$ IS the original of $f'(x)$. It does not have to start from a fixed function. In real life, for example, the work done by a force $f(x)$ along $x$ can be computed by integral of $f(x)$. Or the distance traveled by some object with a velocity function $f(x)$ is $F(x)$. I am sure you will see some applications of them in calculus.